# Merge the tags “angular2” and “angularjs-2.0”?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The two tags, [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) and [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) describe the exact same subject. [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) ought to be preferred.

Comment: The v1 tag is [tag:angularjs] and tags here commonly use a dash to separate the version number, so [tag:angularjs-2.0] should be preferred. Although I'm not sure if the *.0* part should be there.

Comment: The official package name is angular2, https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2.

Comment: Also there is [angularjs-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2), which is separate from `angularjs-2.0`.  Yeah, this is a mess.  I think I would vote for keeping it the same as the package name, as @GajusKuizinas mentioned.  Whatever is decided, the three tags need to be merged to something.

Answer (score 6):

Part of the issue with all of this is that what we might collectively know as v2 of AngularJS is actually being called just [Angular](https://angular.io/) with anything less than v2 being referred to as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). You can also see this reflected in their GitHub repos.

If we were to follow the current branding, [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) should be de-synonymized from [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and the tag wiki updated to explain it's for Angular v2 while the other tag is for AngularJS less than v2. With that split, synonyms can be created for the new [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag to have [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) and pretty much any other combination of the words angular and 2 that might show up in a tag name. The same can be done for the [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag for things like [angular-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-1.4) or whatever if we find those creeping up.

Comment: What about renaming [tag:angular] tag to [tag:angular1] and merging all tags that refer to version two to [tag:angular] tag?

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Did you mean angularjs to angular1? Either way, it doesn't make that much sense since no one refers to the original framework as angular1. I'll flush out my answer more to explain what I think makes that most sense.