# The AngularJS-2.0 Tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

The [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) tag will quickly get out of date once the first update of Angular 2 is released (e.g. AngularJS 2.1.x.x).

I propose that the tag be renamed to [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2), dropping the minor version number.

On the [AngularJS blog](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/) the two versions are commonly referred to as 'Angular 1' and 'Angular 2'.  We should adopt similar references.

**Edit**

As the comments say, maybe the correct tags should be [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2)?

**Edit 2**

Also pointed out in the comments, the naming used on the Angular websites, follows the format of [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and [angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2).

Comment: I agree. It's not some fluffy web 2.0, it's an actual version number :)

Comment: As far as I know AngularJS 2 is actually a new product with a new API design, not backwards compatible with AngularJS. So heck yes this tag change is very important.

Comment: There's already a fairly popular [tag:angular2] tag that seems like a good candidate too.

Comment: @hvd That's because that is the proper way to reference the framework now. They dropped the JS with the newest version. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300928/merge-the-tags-angular2-and-angularjs-2-0/300963#300963

Comment: I thought angularjs is version 1 and angular ( without the js ) is version 2 :)
so angularjs vs angular should do fine right? angular2 as the tag might make it more explicit and clear

Comment: TBH I'm hoping they'll do a rebrand to a completely different name, just so it's possible to Google for code examples.  Other JavaScript libraries that have undergone lots of breaking changes through the versions are a nightmare to find working code samples for.

Comment: I hope we find soon a better naming for Angular tags. We are discussing this specific problem for a long time. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291430/1476885).

Comment: It seems the names used by the AngularJS team are Angular 2 and AngularJS (1).
Browse the AngularJS website and look at the download links of each version.
Then, go on the Angular 2 website and search the word "AngularJS", there are not any.

Comment: I'm not a regular on meta, but what happens now?  It feels like I asked the void a question, some witnesses passed comment on my question and the void didn't reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I totally vote for `angular2`.

Just see their [news](https://angular.io/news.html) section. They always refer to **Angular 2** (yes, there's a space, we can skip it instead of putting a dash). They do the same in their [features](https://angular.io/features.html) section.

If you go to their [support](https://angular.io/support.html) section you'll see three tags (referencing StackOverflow) :

- [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)
- [angular2-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-forms)
- [angular2-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)

**Update**

Recently to the support section was added the subreddit [/r/Angular2](https://www.reddit.com/r/angular2/). Thanks @john for the heads up!

Ammount of questions asked per tag (at the moment I write this)

- angular2 - 1663
- angularjs-2.0 - 164
- angularjs-2 - 39

I've been sharing in chats, answering questions, reading articles, etc, and haven't seen anybody refering to the new angular as `angularjs-2` nor `angularjs-2.0`.

Even more, check their repo (yes, the repo doesn't contain the version number), but all their source code is under [angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2).

It's just easier, it's clear that it refers to the new version, it doesn't contain an unecessary dash nor *dot something*.

Comment: it is `/r/Angular2` on Reddit. so why not?

Comment: You're totally right @john, I forgot aQutie sent a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/901) to add it to the website! I'll update it.

Comment: FYI. The news link from above is a '404' now.  It appears google is going with angularjs (angular 1) and just plain angular (angular >=2).